How to change the line-height only in the code chunk when using Rmd in Rstudio
I'm looking for a way to modify the .rstheme file and adjust the line-height in a R markdown document. Specifically I want the code chunk in the Rmd file to have a line-height of 1.2 and for the other parts i want it to be 4.
.ace_marker-layer .ace_foreign_line {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

Rmd
I tried tweaking the .ace_marker-layer .ace_foreign_line selectors but it did not work. Help will be appreciated.
